# Array 2 dimension loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array like this :

A =

```
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 0

17 18 19 20 21 0  0  0

22 23 24 25 26 27 28 0
```

then I want to transform array `A` to `B` which look like this one

B =

```
10 11 12 13 14 

15 16  0  0  0

17 18 19 20 21

22 23 24 25 26

27 28  0  0  0
```

Here is what I have done :

```
 public class tesMapping {

    static int a [][]= new int [][]{{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,0},
                             {17,18,19,20,21,0,0,0},
                             {22,23,24,25,26,27,28,0}};
    static int b [][]=new int [5][5];
    static int j=0;

    public static void main (String args[]){
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for (j=0;j<5;j++)
                b[i][j]=a[i][j];
            int k=5;
            for (k=5;k<8;k++){
             if (a[i][k]!=0){
                 i++;
                 b[i][j]=a[i][k];         
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

The program still error, truly I have no idea anymore, can somebody help me?

Comment: the error is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: No, actually b[5] does not exist. `i++` is incorrect.

Comment: then how to make new row for the element in first row if they > 5? should I make the new loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int posBx = 0, posBy = 0;

    for (int posAx = 0; posAx < a.length; posAx++) {
        for (int posAy = 0; posAy < a[posAx].length; posAy++) {

            if (posBy == b[posBx].length) {
                posBy = 0;
                posBx++;
            }
            if (posBx == b.length) {
                posBx = 0;
                posBy++;
            }
            b[posBx][posBy++] = a[posAx][posAy];

        }

    }
}
```

for a.length < b.length

Answer (score 0):

You array sizes don't match, you increment `i` beyond the size of `b`.
Rethink your use of variables. Try using four variables: `srcX`, `srcY`, `dstX`, `dstY`.
Then increment `dstX`/`dstY` (whichever you want to use for the rows) only twice: between the two inner loops and at the end of the outer loop, along with the matching `src_`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the static int a, b and j inside your method (drop the static then), you can debug your program and see your variables. I'v been trying to solve it for 5 minutes and I have found already several little mistakes. Try to debug it and if you're stuck again, let us know.